# LinkedIn API - 409 Conflict response from POST /ugcPosts

Tags: linkedin-api

**Preface: I submitted a support ticket to LinkedIn about this but they redirected me here with the response:**

> I am sorry for the inconvenience this has caused to you. I request you to kindly use the below link to contact Stack overflow for your API related query: https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/53170?hcppcid=homepage

**What I sent in my ticket:**

Starting over the weekend (8/1), we began seeing an increase in 409 Conflict responses. [According to LinkedIn's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/ugc-post-api) this indicates that the post is a duplicate of another post created in the last 10 minutes, however looking into this ourselves we've verified that this is not the case. We've made no changes to our integration, so we know this is nothing on our end either.

Here's an example response:
{"message":"com.linkedin.content.common.ResponseException: RestliServiceException thrown in chimera; Write conflict when trying to update UGC: urn:li:share:[redacted]","status":409}

A similar issue posted on StackOverflow at the time of writing this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63232641/com-linkedin-restli-client-restliresponseexception-errors-since-august-01st-with

^ This has since been removed for being a tech support question, which I agree with, but LinkedIn's not giving us any other options here.

---

I'm not sure why they redirected me to Stack Overflow or how they expect Stack Overflow to help here, so I've replied to their ticket but made this post in the meantime just in case.

Any ideas for what might be wrong on our end would be appreciated!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as you surmise, linkedin support shouldn't have sent you here. Perhaps if you point them at a closed question here they will recognise that.

Comment: Update - It appears whatever issue was happening on their end has been fixed; we stopped receiving these errors 8/3 around 3pm EDT. Feel free to close, thank you!